# C++ Perfect Forwarding function

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference, lvalue, perfect-forwarding

I've read about perfect forwarding, but still I've got questions)

Consider this code

```
template<typename Input , typename Output>
struct Processor 
{
    Output process(Input&& input)
    {
        startTimer(); // Starting timer
        auto data = onProcess(std::forward<Input>(input)); // Some heavy work here
        stopTimer(); // Stopping timer
        logTimer(); // Logging how many ms have passed
        return data;
    }

protected:
    Output onProcess(Input&& input) = 0; // one overload for rvalue-references
    Output onProcess(const Input& input) = 0; // one overload for const lvalue-references
};
```

My problem is that `onProcess(Input&& input)` and `onProcess(const Input& input)` will always *do the same*. How can I have one overload for both **const lvalue reference** and **rvalue reference**, will having one **const lvalue reference** cost me memory and performance? Also what if I had an overload with `onProcess(Input& input)` how could I solve my problem then?

**UPDATE**

My example was not using perfect forwarding, so I've corrected it for the right context of the question

```
template<typename Input , typename Output>
struct Processor 
{

    template<class I, 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<I>, Input>, int>=0>
    Output process(I&& input)
    {
        startTimer(); // Starting timer
        auto data = onProcess(std::forward<I>(input));
        stopTimer(); // Stopping timer
        logTimer(); // Logging how many ms have passed
        return data;
    }
protected:
    Output onProcess(Input&& input) = 0; // one overload for rvalue-references
    Output onProcess(const Input& input) = 0; // one overload for const lvalue-references
};
```

Comment: this isnt perfect forwarding. Read about universal references

Comment: Thanks will update the question

Comment: sorry, I didn't want to point out something you should improve on your quesiton. I just pointed out a false premise. Better do not edit the question substantially after you received answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect forwarding is possible when you have a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Example:

```
template<class I, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<I, Input>, int> = 0>
Output process(I&& input)
{
    startTimer(); // Starting timer
    auto data = onProcess(std::forward<I>(input));
    stopTimer(); // Stopping timer
    logTimer(); // Logging how many ms have passed
    return data;
}
```

As for the `virtual` function `onProcess`, you can't have a similar construct there since `virtual` functions can't be function templates. Since both overloads are supposed to do the same thing without changing the object, only make one of those functions and take the `Intput` by `const&`.

Comment: `std::is_same_v<I,Input>` is too restrictive, you probably want `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<I>, Input>`. or `std::is_convertible`.

Comment: Thanks will update my question))